# Reoccurring Outlook appointments not appearing in calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

I've set up a Outlook appointment to re-occur every other day for 40 weeks (way for me to remember some of the more forgetful tasks i need to do)

I've created the appointment and have setup the re-occurrence accordingly however it's only showing the 1st appointment of the series on my calendar rather than the full 120 (3 appointments a week spread over 40 weeks of re-occurrence)

I'm using Outlook 2016 and Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit

Comment: I am using Outlook 2010 Home Office on a PC. I'm having the same problem for **all** appointments (recurring or not, previously entered or new). By experimenting, I've determined the problem occurs only for entries that have a start/stop time. The entries marked as "all day" appear as expected.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of the following steps solved it for me:

1. Change the size of the calendar, expanding or collapsing it.
2. Change the details of the calendar View (Low Detail or Medium Detail or High Detail.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 in different combinations.

I finally hit on a "sweet spot" between the calendar size and high detail.

Again, this was on Outlook 2010 Home Office on a PC.